# Spring OAuth2 preflight returns 302

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, angular

I using OAuth2 in Spring and have a resource server and authentication server. I try to do send a GET to the resource server from Angular2. I get 302 in response for the OPTIONS. I don't see anything in the logs. Neither in the resource server nor the authorization server.

Does anyone have any tip on how to debug this? It is probably Spring that sends back 302 somehow before my code is reached.

Here is my angular code (keeping the commented out lines to show what I have tried already)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthHttp } from 'angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';


import { tokenNotExpired } from 'angular2-jwt';
import { Common } from '../common/common';

@Injectable()
export class ResourceService {

   constructor(private authHttp: AuthHttp, private http: Http) {
   }

   getResource(): Observable<any> {
       console.debug('requesting resources... tokenNotExpired: ' + tokenNotExpired());
       let headers = new Headers();
       headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
      //  headers.append('Access-Control-Request-Method', 'GET');
       let authToken = localStorage.getItem(Common.tokenName);
      //  console.debug('authToken: ' + authToken)
       var authJson = JSON.parse(authToken);
      //  console.debug('authJson: ' + authJson);
      //  console.debug()
        headers.append('Authorization', `Bearer ${authToken}`);
        headers.append('x-access-token', authToken);

      //headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + localStorage.setItem(Common.tokenName));
      return this.authHttp.get('http://localhost:9998/resource', { headers: headers });
      //return this.http.get('http://localhost:9998/resource', {headers: headers}).map(res => res.json());
      //return this.http.get('http://localhost:9998/resource').map(res => res.json());
   }
}
```

Comment: a 302 is a redirect. where do you get redirected to? have you tried doing this with 'curl -vv <url>' so you can see the output?

Comment: That is the tricky part. I've tried with postman to send the OPTIONS with the headers I can see that the Angular2 app is sending. Then I get 200 Back. But I'm guessing that I'm redirected to some whitelabel error message. But all the different filters I have added for trying to solve this is triggered when sending from postman. So something is blocking my filters when sending from Angular2. Have no clue how to figure out what.

Comment: got it. that's useful. i would suggest posting your Angular code here so someone with more Angular experience than me can make sure your code looks correct. any verbose flags you can add to your call that might generate more detailed response would be helpful. that's usually my first approach to a problem like this -- add more verbosity :) GL.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is for all of us Spring newbies.

40.000 combinations of trials later I think that I've found the problem with 302. I had server.context path set to "resource". I think that is what caused the redirect in the OPTIONS.